# SQL data connection extract loses format in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have an Excel view which utilises a SQL Server connection into its database for its data.

Part of the data extracted is a date, which the SQL query requests in 103 (dd/mm/yyyy) format.

```
convert (varchar(11), [mytable].[myDate], 103)'my date'
```

If I run the SQL code direct within SQL Server Manager, copy and past it direct into Excel all is fine.

However as soon as I run it as a SQL data connection within Excel the data seems to lose its format and become a text string. (note in below image how date is justified to the left)

[image: Excel date as text]

The only solution I can find is within Excel 'text to columns' the column containing the date and set the format as DMY.  This however is only a short term fix as every time the data connection is refreshed the format is lost again.

[image: text to columns fix]

[image: correct formatting]

External Data Properties within Excel are set to preserve cell formatting.

[image: data properties]

Apart from writing some VBA to automatically 'text to columns' format on a data refresh does anyone have any ideas.

Date is stored in the underlying database as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss, do I need to extract this in a different format to 103?

Thanks all.

Comment: Why don't you just request the data as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss and use cell formatting to format it as desired.

Comment: As salman indicates, I also think you should just request the data as a DATETIME from the db, not a "string that looks like a date" - excel will know what to do with a date, format the columns using your preferred date format. DOn't use a database to transform data from a native format (int, date, float etc) into a string, and then hope the front end can parse it back to native to do something with it; keep it as native and have the front end work with it as native

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Salman / Caius.  Amended SQL query to take the native format and then played around with it in the front end.